# Context menu API: Is there a way to know which button was used to select an item?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, contextmenu, mouseevent

I'm currently playing with the context menu API for extension in Chrome.
I added some items in the context menu and I receive well the "onclick" event on my menu items.

But there seems to be no difference between a left click and a right click, and no event is triggered with middle click.

So the question is: Is there a way to know which button was used to select an item?

If no, I would like to suggest to add this feature to the API, but I don't know the proper way to do so.

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to know this with the current API. I suspect it is an application-level restriction, since none of Chrome's context options behave differently on right versus left click.

You can put in a feture request on the [Chromium bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list).  Make it very clear *why* you want this feature (i.e., describe your specific project), since at face value, it doesn't sound like something very many people would ever use; most people will probably settle for creating multiple context menu items to achieve multiple effects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link! I'm heading to the tracker right now.

Comment: For an example of UI precedent, you can point out Firefox context menu items do behave different on middle click (Back and Forward open new windows on middle click).